# Selection Sort Check wheather its correct or not

Tags: java, arrays

Check Whether the algorithm is correct or not, I developed it by writing and but the algorithm given in online is where size is reduced in first for loop :|

```
class Selectionsort {
    public void sort(int[] arr,int size) {
        int minimum = 0;
        for(int j =0;j < size;j++) {
            for(int i = j; i < size;i++) {
                if(arr[i] < arr[minimum]) {
                    minimum = i;
                }
            }
            int temp = arr[minimum];
            arr[minimum] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            System.out.println("\n");
            for(int x : arr) {
                System.out.print( x + " ");
            }
        }
    }  
}
public class HEllo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int size = input.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[size];
    for(int i=0; i< size;i++) {
        arr[i] = rand.nextInt(20);
    }
    for(int i : arr) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");

    Selectionsort S = new Selectionsort();
    S.sort(arr, size);
}
```

}

Comment: Are there any issues with your algorithm or do you just want somebody to check it? If it's the first, then explain what the issues are; if it's the second, then I suggest you move this question to [codereview.SE].

Comment: You may want to write a series of unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your method is not correct.

Test run:

```
    int[] a = { 3, 5 };
    sort(a, a.length);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Expected output:

> ```
> [3, 5]
> ```

Observed output:

> ```
> 3 5 
>
> 5 3 [5, 3]
> ```

I believe that your problem is that the value of `minimum` survives between iterations of the outer loop. So if for one `j` you found `minimum = j`, then for the next `j`, `minimum` will still be `j - 1`, so you will be swapping into the part of the array that was already sorted, effectively ruining the sorting you had done.

I suggest that instead you declare `minimum` inside the outer `for` loop. Then it will also be clearer that `0` is not the correct initial value. I leave it to you to find a correct one.